# Failed begin transaction with Databricks warehouse

Tags: go, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to run multiple queries in one Databricks transaction. I am using golang for that. But getting `not implemented` error.
When I look at the library [code](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go/blob/36b12cd566fecb64cb0c06dc61a71fa3c2c62848/connection.go#L55C32-L63):

```
// Not supported in Databricks.
func (c *conn) Begin() (driver.Tx, error) {
    return nil, dbsqlerrint.NewDriverError(context.TODO(), dbsqlerr.ErrNotImplemented, nil)
}

// Not supported in Databricks.
func (c *conn) BeginTx(ctx context.Context, opts driver.TxOptions) (driver.Tx, error) {
    return nil, dbsqlerrint.NewDriverError(context.TODO(), dbsqlerr.ErrNotImplemented, nil)
}
```

Is there a way I can run multiple queries in one transaction in databricks?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Databricks. See [How are transactions scoped on Databricks?](https://docs.databricks.com/lakehouse/acid.html#how-are-transactions-scoped-on-databricks)
:

> Databricks manages transactions at the table level. Transactions always apply to one table at a time. For managing concurrent transactions, Databricks uses optimistic concurrency control. This means that there are no locks on reading or writing against a table, and deadlock is not a possibility.
>
> By default, Databricks provides snapshot isolation on reads and write-serializable isolation on writes. Write-serializable isolation provides stronger guarantees than snapshot isolation, but it applies that stronger isolation only for writes.
>
> Read operations referencing multiple tables return the current version of each table at the time of access, but do not interrupt concurrent transactions that might modify referenced tables.
>
> **Databricks does not have BEGIN/END constructs that allow multiple operations to be grouped together as a single transaction.** Applications that modify multiple tables commit transactions to each table in a serial fashion. You can combine inserts, updates, and deletes against a table into a single write transaction using `MERGE INTO`.